# How to pass `self` to a function that takes `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?` in Swift?

Tags: swift, pointers

I've bought a 3D 4K projector last year, and it uses DLP-Link technology, which requires an 120fps Left/Right alternating video stream for stereoscopy.

I'm writing a player in Swift for Mac using Core Video, and a function require me to pass an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?` (`void *` in Obj-C) to it, and I'm passing the view instance to it using the `self` keyword.

Here's my code:

```
//
//  MovieView.swift
//  Studio Media Player
//
//  Created by DannyNiu on 2022-07-03.
//

import Foundation
import Cocoa

import AVFoundation
import CoreVideo

class MovieView : NSView
{
    var asset: AVAsset?
    var player: AVPlayer?
    var item: AVPlayerItem?
    var vout: AVPlayerItemVideoOutput?
    var cvpb: CVPixelBuffer?
    var cii: CIImage?
    var cgi: CGImage?
    var irect: CGRect?
    var vlink: CVDisplayLink?
    
    func setup_displaylink() -> Bool
    {
        var cvret: CVReturn
        
        cvret = CVDisplayLinkCreateWithActiveCGDisplays(&vlink)
        if( vlink == nil ) { return false }
        
        var me: MovieView = self
        cvret = CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(
            vlink!, vlink_callback, &me)
        
        if( cvret == kCVReturnSuccess ) {
            return true
        } else { return false }
    }
    
    func assign_asset(_ asset: AVAsset)
    {
        self.asset = asset
        item = .init(asset: asset)
        player = .init(playerItem: item)
        vout = .init()
        cvpb = nil
        cii = nil
    }
    
    func video_render(_ d: CVTimeStamp)
    {
        let t: CMTime = player!.currentTime()
        
        let cgc: CGContext = (NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext)!
        let cic: CIContext = (NSGraphicsContext.current?.ciContext)!
        
        if( vout?.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: t) ?? false )
        {
            cvpb = vout?.copyPixelBuffer(
                forItemTime: t, itemTimeForDisplay: nil)
            cii = .init(cvPixelBuffer: cvpb!)
            irect = cii!.extent
            cgi = cic.createCGImage(cii!, from: irect!)
        }
        
        if( irect == nil ) { return }
        
        let orect: CGRect = NSRectToCGRect(bounds)
        var vrect: CGRect =
        CGRect(origin: orect.origin,
               size: CGSize(width: orect.width * 2,
                            height: irect!.height *
                                    orect.width /
                                    irect!.width))
        
        cgc.setFillColor(gray:0, alpha:1)
        cgc.fill(orect)
        
        if( d.videoTime % 2 == 1 )
        {
            vrect = vrect.offsetBy(dx: -orect.width, dy: 0)
        }
        cgc.draw(cgi!, in: vrect)
    }
}

func vlink_callback(
    displayLink: CVDisplayLink,
    inNow: UnsafePointer<CVTimeStamp>,
    inOutputTime: UnsafePointer<CVTimeStamp>,
    flagsIn: CVOptionFlags,
    flagsOut: UnsafeMutablePointer<CVOptionFlags>,
    arg_mvview: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
) -> CVReturn
{
    let mvview: MovieView = arg_mvview!.load(as: MovieView.self)
    mvview.video_render(inNow.pointee)
    
    return kCVReturnSuccess
}
```

When I debug the program, the `mvview.video_render(inNow.pointee)` line caused an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` trap, with `code = 1`. I assume this is caused by me not correctly passing `self` to the display link call-back. So how can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure that myview is a valid reference. Set a breakpoint and type `po myview` before you call video_render. This also may help: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/exc-bad-access-crash/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Unmanaged` class.

in `setup_displaylink()`:

```
    func setup_displaylink() -> Bool
    {
        var cvret: CVReturn
        
        cvret = CVDisplayLinkCreateWithActiveCGDisplays(&vlink)
        if( vlink == nil ) { return false }
        
        var me: UnsafeMutableRawPointer = 
        Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()
        cvret = CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(
            vlink!, vlink_callback, &me)
        
        if( cvret == kCVReturnSuccess ) {
            return true
        } else { return false }
    }
```

and in `vlink_callback`

```
func vlink_callback(
    displayLink: CVDisplayLink,
    inNow: UnsafePointer<CVTimeStamp>,
    inOutputTime: UnsafePointer<CVTimeStamp>,
    flagsIn: CVOptionFlags,
    flagsOut: UnsafeMutablePointer<CVOptionFlags>,
    arg_mvview: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
) -> CVReturn
{
    let mvview: MovieView =
    Unmanaged.fromOpaque(arg_mvview!).takeUnretainedValue()
    mvview.video_render(inNow.pointee)
    
    return kCVReturnSuccess
}
```

Notice I used the "Unretained" function, because there's no need to add to the reference count of the movie view, as self is being passed around internally. Use "Retained" functions when otherwise appropriate.